# I am having trouble getting ELB to pass health checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elb

health Checks are failing on my ELB for just a sample project. But I've gone through all the tutorials without much help.

The service definitely spins up. I can see it in the logs and I'm exposing 9000

[image]

#### MAIN SERVICE

[image]

#### TARGET GROUP

[image]

#### SECURITY GROUP & RULES

[image]

#### VPC

[image]

#### HEALTH CHECK SETTINGS

### [image]

[image]

#### TASK SETTING

[image]

#### LOGS

[![

---

][9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVDkY.png)][9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVDkY.png)

Comment: Can you show us the **Health check settings** in the Target Group? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir1Ob.png

Comment: Those settings seem good to me. I'm guessing you've deployed Fargate instead of EC2, so that shouldn't take very long to start the container unlike EC2, try increasing the **Interval** to `60` or higher?... You gonna have to try few different configs before you find the right one usually.

Comment: yes, Fargate with a 300 second grace period. I've upped the interval but that doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: Hmm, what's the stopped container logs show? are there any weird error logs?

Comment: no. it just stops. I don't think the container is getting hit at all. I have a log for health checks that is not being recorded.

Comment: Ah, I see where's the problem is... the first photo shows Target group will route traffic to port `80`. You need to change that to `9000`.